# Увеличение и уменьшение размера ReyclerView

Tags: java, android

Есть *Recycler* внутри скрола. Я понимаю,что неправильно, но по-другому никак ни вытащить *Recycler* из скрола.

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня элементы *Recycler'a* состоят из двух частей. При тапе на первой появляется вторая и при еще одном нажатии она исчезает.

Вот код в adpater'e:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.content_head:
            if (content.isShown()) {
                content.measure(0, 0);
                LayTrenn.reSizeRV(content.getMeasuredHeight(), false);
                content.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                content.measure(0, 0);
                content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                LayTrenn.reSizeRV(content.getMeasuredHeight(), true);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

А это там, где RV:

```
public static void reSizeRV(int i, boolean b) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) rv.getLayoutParams();
    if (b) params.height = rv.getHeight() + i;
    else params.height = rv.getHeight() - i;
    rv.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

В данном случае у меня контент, который скрывается и открывается, динамический, а высота берется максимальная из высот всех элементов. Если использовать `getHeight()`, то он не увеличивает с первого раза, а только со второго, так как я понимаю, элемент еще не отрисовался.

Как мне решить проблему с увеличением размера *Recycler'a* на высоту скрытого контента? Если нужны будут детали, то пишите в комментариях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После манипуляций с вьюшкой, попробуйте вызвать у нее `invalidate();`. Данный метод предназначит для рефреша конкретного объекта.

Comment: Попробуем сейчас)

Comment: Нет, не сработало(